# Using nested case statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query like so:

```
UPDATE image
SET angle  = CASE  
WHEN id = 1000 
THEN 90  
ELSE 
angle 
END WHERE 
id IN(1000)
```

As you might have guessed, this SQL is built dynamically so that using a single statement I can update multiple records. What I want is that instead of updating an value directly as say 90 in this case, I want it to be incremental. So I guess I can do:

```
UPDATE image
SET angle  = CASE  
WHEN id = 1000 
THEN angle + 90    //<-- instead of 90, I use (angle + 90)
ELSE 
angle 
END WHERE 
id IN(1000)
```

The only other thing I am trying to figure out is that if (angle + 90) >= 360, then I want the angle field to be 0. I am not sure on how to edit the SQL syntax to make this happen. Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want _any_ value of `angle + 90` to be set to `0`, or do you want to wrap around and increment from `0` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the modulus operator (`%`).  Whenever the expression `angle + 90` exceeds 360 degrees, it will wrap back to zero.

```
UPDATE image
SET angle = CASE  
    WHEN id = 1000 
THEN (angle + 90) % 360
ELSE angle 
END
WHERE id IN(1000)
```

Comment: Yes, it will.  Really, we don't know what his exact requirement is.  I'm betting that he wants the modulus.  Let's see what happens, I'm excited.

Comment: Yeah once I re-read your comment above, I see what you were getting at and you're correct; which is why I deleted my comment. I read the original request that "anything >= 360 should be 0" so I answered based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed do nested `CASE` statements

```
UPDATE image
SET angle  = CASE  
WHEN id = 1000 
THEN 
    CASE WHEN angle >= 270 
    THEN 0
    ELSE angle + 90    //<-- instead of 90, I use (angle + 90)
    END
ELSE 
    angle 
END WHERE 
id IN(1000)
```